# SharePoint 2013 - Download file without content (zero bytes)

Tags: sharepoint-server, download, file-download

I have a SharePoint 2013 with front-ends in different Windows/IIS versions.

1. Windows Server 2012 R2 - IIS v8.5
2. Windows Server 2019 - IIS v10

I uploaded a PDF file as attachment in custom list item. When I try to download this in a front-end with "Windows Server 2012", the file is downloaded correctly with the content, but if I try in a front-end with "Windows Server 2019", the file is downloaded without content (zero bytes).

1. Same configurations in both servers (IIS and web.config);
2. No log is saved in Sharepoint ULSLogs and Event viewer;
3. In both cases, the request http status code is 200;

Some idea what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this all happen in SharePoint 2013?

According to the system requirements of the [official document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-0), SharePoint 2013 does not support windows 2016 or higher versions:

[can SharePoint 2013 be run on Windows Server 2019 and SQL server 2019?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/392851/can-sharepoint-2013-be-run-on-windows-server-2019.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!